# FadeIn WITHOUT .hide() function?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, fadein, animate.css

I want to make a fadeIn effect but I DON'T want to hide it because it screws with margins when the object is literally hidden from the document. I need it to ideally animate from opacity 0, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#item").css("opacity", 0).delay(13000).fadeIn(2000);
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

As you are using `opacity`, you should use [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method instead of the `fadeIn`.

```
$("#item").css("opacity", 0).delay(13000).fadeTo(2000, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function:

```
$("#item").animate({opacity:100}, 2000);
```

The element with the id `item` should have assigned an opacity of 0 to begin with.